# Jupyter Notebook and pip referring to previous uninstalled python version

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have recently uninstalled python 3.7 and installed python 3.9. After that, when I try to use pip to install any package, it keeps trying to use python37.exe, which is not installed anymore. I was able to solve that by using `python -m pip install`, but the same does not work when I try to launch jupyter notebook, which still tries to use python37. I cannot launch it using a similar command `python -m jupyter notebook`.

I was wondering if there is any solution to this, since I could not find anything related to that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you install jupyter notebook on v3.9 of python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you all an update in case anyone is facing the same problem.

I was able to find some remaining files and files of the previous installation of Python 3.7 in my system that were not deleted for some reason during the uninstall process. I deleted them manually and my system started to recognize Python 3.9 to call pip and jupyter after that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to install it again using your new pip like

```
pip install notebook
```

(Sorry not enough reputation for a comment)

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when jupyter is installed with a specific version of python. The easiest / best solution is to uninstall jupyter, then reinstall it with the correct version of python.

In your case, you should consider using `python3.9 -m pip install jupyter` (after first uninstalling jupyter).

Comment: When I installed python 3.9 I installed jupyter just like that. Although the installation was successful, when I try to launch it, it still tries to do so via python3.7. It seems like something related to environment variables (I am on Windows), but I don't see anything suspicious there.

Comment: I'm sorry my solution wasn't helpful. This might be a windows specific issue you're facing @JohnMarvin